# Designing table for historical data from multiple tables

Tags: database-design

I have different kind of fields in different tables that needs to be versioned as historical data .
what is the best way to approach this ?
what I did is to capture one level of grouping fields.
I will maintain look-up nested tables where I specify the type of fields that will be versioned as below

[image]

and the historical table will look something like this .

[image]

Is there any Better way to handle this kind of situation ? keep in mind data to be versioned can vary greatly.

Answer (score 1):

I see 2 approaches for this.

1. You can maintain a history twin for every table you want to keep history about. The original table will always contain the last/current version of items - while the history will contain the historic versions. The history twin tables must not have a primary key because there will be multiple rows with the same ID. You will need to add 2 columns - both to the original table and to the historic twin. The columns will be of type DATETIME and will be called VALID_FROM and VALID_TO. VALID_TO will be NULL in the original table to denote that this is the current version.
2. You can have one global history table with the following columns - TABLE_COLUMN_ID, VALUE, VALID_FROM, VALID_TO. TABLE_COLUMN_ID will be a foreign key into a mapping table from which you will get the name of the original entity and the name of the corresponding column. The column VALUE should be of type TEXT and VALID_FROM/VALID_TO will be of type DATETIME. Like the other approach you will need 2 additional columns in each of the original tables - VALID_FROM/VALID_TO to represent the current version validity period.

The first approach obviously requires more space because it keeps all columns of the versioned tables. The second approach could be a little uncomfortable to work with especially if you need to make too many JOINs to get all of the versioned fields.

Comment: ok you mean in the second approach we will have the primary key as combination of Table_cloumn_ID + validfrom/Valid_to ? .
but now for Table_cloumn_ID what the values will be ? is it a joint Id like table name Owner and ID is 1 Table_cloumn_ID will be Owner_1 ? 
the thing is my data is variable so at a given time A company can have 2 owners and at another given time it can have 4 owners so mapping the IDs from original table is not good way I see .

Comment: The column `TABLE_COLUMN_ID` is an artificial ID - because using integers will take less space compared to what we would have if we've used 2 columns `TABLE_NAME(text)` and `COLUMN_NAME(text)` instead. You will have a table `HISTORY_MAPPING` with columns ID, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME and `TABLE_COLUMN_ID` will be a foreign key into `HISTORY_MAPPING`. You will populate table `HISTORY_MAPPING` inside your trigger which actually does the history storing. And `VALUE` can be a JSON-encoded text if you want to store e.g. 4 or 2 owners of the given company (their IDs).

Comment: In literature I think you can find approach 1 called SCD type 4 and the approach 2 called SCD type 2. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension